# iPhone voice recognition "Vocalkit by KingOFBrian" compile error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, linker, voice-recognition

i'm using last version of **VocalKit** for iPhone https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit

I followed all instructions to add in new project as specified on github,

---

but on compile time i getting these errors:

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Voice.app/Voice normal i386
cd /Users/asd/Desktop/Voice
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer-old/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer-old/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer-old/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer-old/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/asd/Desktop/Voice/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/asd/Desktop/Voice/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/asd/Desktop/Voice/build/Voice.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Voice.build/Objects-normal/i386/Voice.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -all_load -ObjC -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics "/Users/asd/Downloads/KingOfBrian-VocalKit-a25e5f3 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libVocalKit.a" -framework AudioToolbox -liconv -o /Users/asd/Desktop/Voice/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Voice.app/Voice

Undefined symbols:
  "_ssymm_", referenced from:
      _matrixmultiply in libVocalKit.a(matrix.o)
  "_spotrf_", referenced from:
      _determinant in libVocalKit.a(matrix.o)
  "_sposv_", referenced from:
      _invert in libVocalKit.a(matrix.o)
      _solve in libVocalKit.a(matrix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what can i do?
What's the cause of these problems?

I tried to import in xcode3 and xcode4, but it's the same.
My sdk version is 4.3.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all,
but I solved using `google chrome speech`.

[Speech recognition framework for iOS that supports Spanish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519947/speech-recognition-framework-for-ios-that-supports-spanish/7529974#7529974)

Using `chromium src`: src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/content/browser/speech/

Answer (score 1):

from the readme file on the github page...

I no longer advise using VocalKit, as a much better project, Open Ears has come out. http://www.politepix.com/openears/

Maybe check out openears?