# Speech recognition framework for iOS that supports Spanish

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, speech-recognition

Is there a speech to text framework for iOS that supports Spanish out of the box? Commercial or OS is ok.

Comment: does the speech recognition service by Google work  with the iOS?

Answer (score 9):

There are a bunch of commercial IOS librariers for speech recognition. The names I keep hearing are Nuance, iSpeech, and Yapme. Each offers cloud speech recognition (off the device) and a client library and SDK to build into your app.

Nuance seems to support Spanish - http://blog.dragonmobileapps.com/2011/01/mobile-app-developer-dragon-mobile-sdk.html

> ...you can speech-enable your app for including US and UK English,
>   European Spanish, European French, German, Italian and Japanese---with
>   even more languages on tap for 2011!

and now Nuance gives developers free access - http://www.masshightech.com/stories/2011/09/26/daily13-Nuance-tweaks-mobile-dev-program-with-free-access-to-Dragon.html

iSpeech is likely to support Spanish - http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone

> iSpeech's Mobile SDKs support 27 TTS and ASR (defined grammar)
>   languages and 15 languages for free-form dictation voice recognition.

Yapme, sorry, I'm not sure - http://yapinc.com/speech-cloud.html

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/content/browser/speech/

It's the **Chrome Browser Speech to search**...... you can do it in Objective-C. Try go google.com on chrome browser and if spanish is recognized, you win! :)

You can easily use:

```
- (void) SpeechFromGooglezzz {
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US"];

  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"tmpAudio.flac"];

  NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  [request addPostValue:myData forKey:@"Content"];
  [request addPostValue:@"audio/x-flac; rate=16000" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
  [request startSynchronous];

  NSLog(@"req: %@", [request responseString]);
}
```

Remember that you must recording a 16000 bitrate FLAC file! Or nothing!

Google responds with a json containing the words.

hope this helps.

Comment: My understanding is that Google is not providing these services for commercial use except for Chrome and Android clients. I wouldn't build a commercial application using those APIs from IOS. Google could easily  shut down your application. If it is just a prototype or experiment, you might get away with using the Google services, but I would not rely on them for commercial purposes.

Comment: Right, but Fernando don't specified if the app is commercial or not! :)

Comment: True, a good link to see is http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Answer (score 1):

I've written a client library for the Google Speech APIs. Works best with iOS and also supports other Unix-like systems:

Edit: try here: https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec