# what to do for voice application for ios?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

how to make Vlingo like application?
is there any api that can be used for making apps for ios?
Please provide some guide line or any tutorials or an help or comment will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

i also like to know how the talking ben the dog and talking tom cat is working as we talk it repeats it in funny voice. how it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Speech Recognition on iOS, there have been many similar questions. Please see [Speech to text Conversion.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776402/speech-to-text-conversion) or [Text-to-speech (voice generation) and speech-to-text (voice recognition) APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348770/text-to-speech-voice-generation-and-speech-to-text-voice-recognition-apis) or [Speech recognition framework for iOS that supports Spanish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519947/speech-recognition-framework-for-ios-that-supports-spanish) or [What is the current best speech recognition API for ios to match few keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202583/what-is-the-current-best-speech-recognition-api-for-ios-to-match-few-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

For the recognition of text you can use:

- https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src

For speech recognition testing to see here

- http://www.politepix.com/openears

Comment: this is a good staring point for new bee like me thanks a lot.

Comment: OpenEars contains a Flite implementation, so you don't need to also include iphone-tts (iphone-tts is good but it would be redundant to add it to a project that already includes OpenEars).