# How to create the voice recognition in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, voice-recognition

I want to create voice recognition based application. Is there any default delegate function or framework available in iOS 5+? How to do voice recognition?

Comment: You can't use the built-in ASR capabilities of Siri. If you plan to write your on ASR you are facing lots of work.

Comment: @Thedude so there is any other way pls help me

Comment: This question has been asked before. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137057/what-to-do-for-voice-application-for-ios?lq=1